# set all backwards-compatible settings to chroot

Tags: postfix

I successfully upgraded my server from Debian lenny all the way to stretch. now when I start postfix I get lots of warnings that it uses the backward-compatible mode.

I selected the offending lines in `master.cf` with

`$ grep "backwards-compatible" mail.log|cut -c 60-999|cut -d: -f2|sort|uniq|cut -d\  -f3|grep -v default|sort -n|xargs`

```
9 10 20 21 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 32 34 37 38 39 42 43 44 78
```

Now all those lines don't show a setting in the `chroot` column at

```
for l in 6 9 10 20 21 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 32 34 37 38 39 42 43 44 78; do sed -n ${l}p /etc/postfix/master.cf; done
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
...
```

I successfully set one option with

```
# postconf -F smtp/inet/chroot=y
# postfix reload
```

(source: http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html#chroot )

But how do I set all settings to `chroot=y` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly edit and set all offending lines to `y` in the column for chroot in `/etc/postfix/master.cf` like

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

then reload the config with with

```
systemctl reload postfix.service
```